# android how to show 'complete action using' dialog even if only one application is there

Tags: android

My application has some documents to show.
The activity is having one button : 'Open In'.
When I click on this button, some popup should display like  'complete action using' dialog, to list the applications which support the document. When I select the appropriate app, then only document should be display with that icon.

I used the following code. It is working fine, if there are more than one application which support that document. But If there is only one application, the document is directly opening without showing popup.

How to show 'complete action using' dialog always?

```
Intent docViewIntent = new Intent();                
docViewIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
File file = new File("/sdcard/docs/myfile.pdf"); 
Uri fileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
docViewIntent.setDataAndType(fileUri, "application/pdf");
docViewIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
try
{
    Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(docViewIntent, "Choose application");                     
    startActivity(chooser);
} 
catch (ActivityNotFoundException e)
{
    Toast.makeText(this,  "No Application Available to View file", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You would have to implement your own "chooser"-style dialog (or dialog-themed activity), using data from `PackageManager` and `queryIntentActivities()`.

From Android's perspective, there is no value in forcing the user to tap on a choice that is their only choice, which is why the chooser is skipped in case of a single matching activity.